# How to open this LVDS connector?

Tags: connector, lvds, ffc

I'm having trouble disconnecting the dual LVDS cables from a Philips PFL6008 main board. These don't seem to have a "flip-up" type of bracket, but the 2 small black taps on the top look as if they can be pulled (or maybe also pushed).  Still, I don't dare apply too much force to the cable or connector without some knowledge on how it is supposed to open (and attempts with limited force so far failed).  So, can anyone give me some info on the connectors below?

[image: Side view]

[image: Front view]

Comment: The black tabs move LEFT in teh top picture, i.e. OUT from he connector (along the flex PCB).

Comment: Sad, but I recognized that as a Philips mainboard by the 4-digit ref-des's. (I spent several years in a Philips Television prototype workshop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push those two small black taps you mentioned. Push gently but firmly and then pull the cable. Unless the mechanism is broken that is the way. I have added two yellow arrows to indicate those points.

[image]

Comment: Nice. I've never seen a push-down one before (and I've seen a lot of FPC connectors).